# How to set "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet" annotation using Terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm, terraform-provider-azure

I want to set the following annotation using Terraform

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |-
  location ~* /admin {
    allow xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    deny all;
}
```

I can set the annotation as long as it is a string like mentioned below

```
resource "helm_release" "keycloak" {
  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart      = "keycloak"
  namespace  = kubernetes_namespace.keycloak.metadata[0].name
  name       = "keycloak"

  set {
    name  = "replicaCount"
    value = 1
  }
}
```

but I don't see any reference for **"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet:"**

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |-
  location ~* /admin {
    allow xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: What is the value you want to set? This entire `location` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about to use yamlencode? Here is just an example:

```
set {
  name = "server\\.resources"
  value = yamlencode({
    limits = {
      cpu    = "200m"
      memory = "50Mi"
    }
    requests = {
      cpu    = "100m"
      memory = "30Mi"
    }
  })
}
```